# Can a teen age girl can shave her head due to lice and hair loss problems

Tags: women, allah, dua

Shaving head due to lice and hair problems

Comment: This is mostly a medical issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
            In the name of Allah, the Entirely merciful, the Especially merciful
```

> Can a teen age girl can shave her head due to lice and hair loss
>   problems?

According to Shia Islam (e.g. based on Ayatollah Khamenei and Ayatollah Sistani as two famous Shia scholars/Marja'al-Taqlids):

**Women can shave their head hairs --actually it is permissible--, but they cannot  be in front of non-mahram(s) without hijab** (and in truth, they cannot be attended --without covering their hairs when there is/are non-mahram(s))--.

Reference:

[http://hadana.ir/](http://hadana.ir/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%DA%A9%DA%86%D9%84-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%88-%D8%AF%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/)